# Puttting together binding navigators in a project

Tags: vb.net, binding, navigator

I am working on a group project in vb.net, in which all my team members are working on individual tables of a database. All of us are using binding navigator,where the GUI is created by drag and drop from the table.

Is it possible to attach all these pieces together with imports or references? 
Will the changes made to the database while working on the program like table adapter can create problem? Do I need to make all those changes in database before importing ?

Can you please give suggestions to put the project together.

Answer (score 0):

By binding the particular combo box to the original table the data need not be re-entered in that particular combo box.It appears at run time. I think my question was not clear that is why I did not get any answer